# is there a way to detect the physical button press on a Droid X?

Tags: android

I realize the Camera button on the Droid X is not a standard feature across all phones, so, I'm curious how to attach a callback to it.  I have a camera application that I wrote and I want the user to be able to snap the picture by pressing that button, but currently it doesn't work that way, so, I'm wondering how to attach my callback to it.

Comment: Have a look at the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986602/android-unregister-camera-button